# Tensorflow unrolled LSTM longer than input sequence

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to create an LSTM in tensorflow to predict time-series data. My training data is a set of input/output sequences of different lengths. Can I include multiple sequences of different lengths in the same training batch? Or do I need to pad them to equal lengths? If so, how?

Also: What will tensorflow do if the unrolled RNN is longer than the input sequence? The `rnn()` method contains an optional `sequence_length` argument which appears designed to handle this eventuality, but I'm not clear what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to build the model from scratch? Otherwise you might want to look into the translate.py-model. Here your issue is taken care of by:
- padding the input (and output) sequences with a PAD-symbol (basically a neutral "no info"-symbol)
- buckets: For different groups of lengths you can create different buckets (makes sense only if your sequence-lengths are very different shortest to longest

Answer (score 0):

You DONT have to batch inputs/output sequence of same length into a batch. TF has a way to specify the input size. The parameter "sequence_length", controls the number of time steps a cell is unrolled. So the TF will unroll your cell only up to sequence_length but not to the step size.

So while feeding the inputs and outputs also feed a sequence_length array which contain the length of each input

```
 tf.nn.bidirectional_rnn(fwd_stacked_lstm_cells, bwd_stacked_lstm_cells, 
                          reshaped_inputs,                                                                                 
                          sequence_length=sequence_length)
```

.....

```
feed_dict={
    model.inputs: x,
    model.targets: y,
    model.sequence_length: lengths})
```

where

- len(lengths) == batch_size and
- for all i, lengths[i] == length of input x[i] (same as length of outpu y[i])